# VB.Net Regex.IsMatch for everything except letters

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am wondering if someone could tell what the Regex sequence is for every type of characters except for Alphabetic characters. My current sequence does not check for some symbols, I have not been able to find a working sequence that covers my needs.

```
For Each c As Char In courseA
        If Regex.IsMatch(c, "^[0-9 ]+$") Then
            lblMsg.Text += "Position of " + courseA + " contains a  non alphabetic characater."

            errorCount = True

        End If

    Next
```

Comment: Check if the character is not [`Char.IsLetter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.isletter(v=vs.110).aspx). If you only need to check if a char is not an ASCII letter, use a `[^a-zA-Z]` regex.

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like `([^a-zA-Z])` to negate all letters.

For negating alphanumeric, you can try `[^a-zA-Z0-9]`